# How do i get the first and last day value per month in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So i have a huge CSV where i would like to get the data (from one specific Column) from the first and last day of every month.
I thought of using pandas for it since i have worked a little bit with it.
What i have so far:

```
import logging
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

# Define Logger
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.info('Start of program')

# set working directory
os.chdir("Path to CSVs")

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';') for f in all_filenames])
logging.info('Combining all CSVs into one....')
combined_csv['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(combined_csv.Timestamp)
logging.info('Transforming Timestamps into datetime....')
res = combined_csv.groupby(combined_csv.index.date).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[0, -1]])
res.index = res.index.droplevel(0)

print(res)
```

Since i'm a beginner in Pandas i don't know how to move on form there. I get back an error.
Do i have got the wrong datatype?

```
AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can sort by `date`
then try:

```
df.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)
df['month'] = df.date.dt.to_period('M')
df.groupby(['month'])['column'].agg(['first', 'last'])
```